# Removing White-space after using "top" tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am working on [This site!!](http://fortrex.malcolmtanti.com/test/), and I'm having a little problem.

I know it may be pretty basic, but I cannot seem to get it to work :/

At the bottom of my site, at the footer I have a whitespace which I want removed. I have tried using the `margin-bottom` to no avail

Is there something else I should be doing?

This is my Code:

> HTML

```
 <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <div id="bottombanner">
    </div>
```

> CSS

```
    #footer{
    background: url("../images/footer.gif") no-repeat top left; 
    height: 370px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

    #bottombanner{
      background-color: rgb( 22, 47, 66 );
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
      top: -31px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
 }
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that with a negative value for top, the element appears to move by 31 pixels, but in reality the element remains on the bottom (that being your white space). giving it a negative margin on the other hand, moves the element by 31 pixels.

Comment: Very good explanation, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in `#bottombanner` `top` to `margin-top`.

```
#bottombanner{
      background-color: rgb( 22, 47, 66 );
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
      margin-top: -31px;/*this*/
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the property `top:-31px` to `margin-top:-31px;` for  `#bottombanner`